# Shortened verbs with remaining preposition

Tags: prepositions

What would be the explanation for using "**to**" after "**wants**" in this sentence and overall?

> If you want to send a message without anybody being able to listen in
>   on it, there are two basic ways of doing this:
>
> 1. have a secure channel
> 2. send the message on the open air, but disguise it
>
> We’ll consider the second approach to this, so we’ll assume that anybody who **wants** **to**
>   can see the message.

Comment: /Send a message over a secure channel or Broadcast it over the  air./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non repetition of main idea:

If you have a main idea, you do  not need to repeat it after certain verbs of volition + to that would re-express the main idea:

Anyone who wants to [play tennis] may play with us this afternoon.

[...]so we’ll assume that anybody who wants to [see the message] can see the message.

**Want to, like to, would like to, would hate to, would prefer to**
Simpler examples to help them stick in your mind:

I'm going to the movies at five. Do you want to [go to the movies at five]?

She's swims 10 miles every day. I'd hate to [swim ten miles every day].

They'd love to come for lunch on Saturday. I'd love to [come for lunch on Saturday] too.

Answer (score 2):

It's a parallel construction.  It means:

> ... anybody who wants to *see the message* can *see the message*.

The form is "want to (verb)"

> I want to eat breakfast.
>
> She wants to watch television.

You could rewrite what you quoted as follows, and not force the reader to backtrack:

> ... anybody who wants to see the message can.

Or you could write it verbosely.

> ... anybody who wants to see the message can see the message.
>
> ... anybody who wants to see the message can see it.